# Android Studio does not run project at first click, runs at second click

Tags: android, project

When I click run icon at Android Studio app installs but does not run on the phone then I click run icon again and it runs.It was not like that before.Do you guys have any solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this go to File->Invalidate caches / restart.

Answer (score 0):

Try =  Clean the project and go to File->Invalidate caches / restart.